# Why is Glass missing Google Play Services?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-glass

What is the reasoning behind not including google plays services on google glass ?
Will they be added in the future ?

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that Google Play Services on Glass will be added in the future. There is an issue that has been "accepted", though with medium priority (see [issue 176 here](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=176&q=Play&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Component%20Summary) from the official Google Glass issue site.